# Try to find the date url was created

Tags: html, google-chrome, url

I had to search but I didn't find the information I needed. Is it possible to access and find out when a webpage accessed on google was created?

I try inspect the code find where is the date and other ways but i didnt find.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Go to google.com and copy-paste the full URL of any web page in the search box and prefix it with the `inurl`: operator.

For instance, if the URL of the page is:

```
https://www.example.com
```

You should write the URL in the Google Search box as:

```
inurl:https://www.example.com
```

Press the Search button and the URL in your browser address bar would read something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:https://www.example.com
```

**Step 2**. Now go to your browser’s address bar - press Ctrl+L on a Windows machine or Cmd+L on Mac - and append &as_qdr=y25 to the end of the Google search URL. Press enter again.

The modified Google search URL would become:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:https://www.example.com&as_qdr=y25
```

The `as_qdr=y25` parameter instructs Google to do a date-based search and retrieve pages that have been indexed by the Googlebot in the past 25 years (in other words, everything).

**Step 3**. Google will load the search results again but this time, you’ll see the actual publication date of the web page next to the title in Google search results.

credit to [this article](https://www.labnol.org/internet/search/find-publishing-date-of-web-pages/8410/).